# Activity not found, no idea why

Tags: android

I'm trying to open a new activity using this code:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Andro.this, Aktivity.class);   
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

The activity to be opened looks like this:

```
package com.andro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Aktivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        try
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        } catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

It is in the same package as the other activity, and in the same directory.

The manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.andro"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name="Andro"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Aktivity">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I've tried with different names like '.Aktivity' '.com.andro.Aktivity' 'Aktivity' 'com.andro.Aktivity'

I delete the bin and gen directories before building.

But still I always get an Activity not found exception in logcat.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the logcat?

Comment: Here's the logcat http://www.radpaste.com/501/

Comment: The error is included in the logcat. I tried prefixing .Andro as well as .Aktivity but the problem persists.

Comment: That's a terrible name for class.

Comment: That's not the real name hehe.

Comment: I tried to simulate your problem with the same activity names and there was no activity not found exception. There is no problem with the method you were using to launch the other activity. May be some where the reference was not getting updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logcat seems to be showing

```
com.andro.Andro$Aktivity not found
```

I think there is another class called Aktivity inside Andro class. So try using this

```
Intent in = new Intent();
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.andro", "com.andro.Aktivity");
in.setComponent(comp);
startActivity(in);
```

Comment: You are right! There was an Aktivity class inside the Andro class. Silly me for not making the connection. I tried your solution and it worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work

```
<activity android:name="com.andro.Aktivity" ........ />
```

Comment: If I literally put it like that I get: [gettype] [Fatal Error] :16:50: Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: @madrops, No, not literally, I meant android:name="com.andro.Aktivity" shall be a part of your Aktivity manifest description. Do you develop in Eclipse? Eclipse does those things for you in Manifest editor

Comment: It was already part of the manifest as I stated in the post. I'm not working in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
<activity android:name=".Andro"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

instead:

```
<activity android:name="Andro"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Edit:

It seems like a problem about your Andro Activity.

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.andro/com.andro.Andro$Aktivity};
```

If you are using a listview in your activity, make sure you extend "ListActivity" as:

```
public class Andro extends ListActivity
```

Comment: Tried that, problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project and restarting eclipse.